# String comparison not working in android

Tags: android

I am trying to compare two string in my application but it fails to compare. I don't know why it fails.

```
    public void processFinish(String output) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), output,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String check="false";
            if(output==check){
                     //doing something here
                }else{
                    //something here
                }
   }
```

the string object **output** has the value **"false"** but always the else block is executed why?
I Tried by changing the `output=="false"` to

```
output.equals(check)
output.equalsIgnoreCase(check)
output.contentEquals(check)
```

nothings works...

Comment: `.equals()` should work

Comment: @Raghunandan Its not working. Thats why I'm here.

Comment: then the strings are not equal likely if not it shoudl work

Comment: try like this `output.trim().equals(check)` ... and see if it holds true

Comment: have you checked the spelling of `false` in variable `output`?

Comment: check your strings you are comparing CareFully...!!!

Comment: Add this `Log.d("MYAPP", "X" + output + ": X" + check + "X");` without the trim(), your mistake will be clear.

Comment: @Simon the question that already has an answer doesn't explain me about the trim() then why i have these down grades :@

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public void processFinish(String output) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), output,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String check="false";
            if(output.trim().equals(check.trim())){
                     //doing something here
                }else{
                    //something here
                }
}
```

your string getting some unwanted blank space from method trim() remove starting and end blank space :) and .equals is a object class method which compare two string :)

Comment: thanks.working fine. but can you explain me what is actually happening there??

Comment: your string getting some unwanted blank space from method trim() remove starting and end blank space :) and  .equals is a object class method which compare two string :)

Comment: @DharanBro what is check. Is there any spaces??

Comment: @BhanuSharma add the explanation to your post.

Comment: @Raghunandan see dude i already added

Comment: @DharanBro see i already added all explanation dude so have u clear what mistake u did

Comment: Nice ans @BhanuSharma... you really deserve an upvote.

Comment: no its very common  @VineetSingh in thz no need to experience just some staring logic and that's it

Answer (score 1):

Since instances of `String` are object, so you can't comparison two objects with `==`. To comparison two `String`, you have to use `equals()` or `equalIgnoreCase()` method.

Replace this

```
if(output==check){
    //doing something here
}else{
    //something here
}
```

with...

```
if(output.equals(check)){
    //doing something here
}else{
    //something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
         if(output.contains(check)== true{
                 //doing something here
            }else{
                //something here
            }
```

Comment: i even used trim(), it didnt work. contains() did the trick

Answer (score 0):

I think output.equals(check) must works

Or your description maybe not correct.May it is not a string of "false" but "false "?

First ,check their length,then use `output.trim().equals(check)`.